# Gitlab - Artifact Size Too Small! Alternatives?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

Be gentle I'm a relatively junior game dev trying his hand at CI/CD - TL;DR we're using Gitlab.com to host our repository and we're trying to use their integrated CI/CD / shared runners to make builds of a game from Unity.

The pipeline is set up and the builds *appear* to work but I'll never know because I get error

> ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 413 Payload
> Too Large  id=[redacted] responseStatus=413 Payload Too Large
> status=413 token=[redacted]

Now - I know that this is because the artifact size is set too small BUT neither me nor my admin can find any way of increasing it - the setting from the docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/continuous_integration.html#maximum-artifacts-size) isn't there for either of us. For what it's worth we think our builds are around 1.3GB at the moment - likely to increase over the year.

Now, because it's hosted and managed on Gitlab.com vs self managed we're not sure if there is any option to increase it whatsoever - and I'm looking for clarity on that - and if not, creative solutions to this issue that you may have used in the past - like if we can upload to a GDrive folder or something. What do you think?

Looked at documentation - emailed account executives - neither resulted in improvements.

Comment: Do you have owner or admin permissions in gitlab?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SaaS on gitlab.com, you cannot increase the maximum artifact size. It is [limited to 1GB](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#gitlab-cicd) (compressed) on gitlab.com

The only thing you can do is to try to reduce the compressed artifact size to less than 1GB.

You can try enabling fastzip with 'slowest' [compression level](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#artifact-and-cache-settings) to see if this helps:

```
myjob:
  variables:
    FF_USE_FASTZIP: "1"
    ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "slowest"
  # ...
```

This *should* reduce the artifact size, but the job will take longer to compress before uploading. Your data may or may not lend itself well to compression, so results may vary.

Alternatively or additionally, you may try to find your own method for compressing your data as part of your job script in a way that is optimal enough to get the size under the 1GB limit.

---

Beyond this, for handling artifacts larger than 1GB, you may have to supply and use your own object storage and artifact handling logic. For example, you can upload your artifacts to your own AWS S3 bucket, then only store the bucket/path details in GitLab artifacts, then use those details to download the artifacts in a subsequent job.

```yaml
myjob:
  script:
    # ...
    # upload artifacts 'manually'
    - S3_PATH="s3://myorg.bucket/path/to/${CI_JOB_ID}/artifacts"
    - aws s3 sync ./artifacts "$S3_PATH"
    # pass artifact path(s) to subsequent jobs
    - echo "$S3_PATH" > artifact-info.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact-info.txt


another_job:
  needs: [myjob]
  before_script:
    # restore artifacts 'manually'
    - S3_PATH="$(cat artifact-info.txt)"
    - aws s3 sync "$S3_PATH" ./artifacts
  # ...
```